# Referencing System.Windows.Forms from a Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a Class Library and need to inherit from PictureBox: `public class Picture : PictureBox { ... }` but `Forms` is not available when I try to add a using directive for it at the top of my Class Library: `using System.Windows.Forms;`. I know that I can get it to work by right-clicking Referenced in Solution Explorer and selecting Add Reference, then adding the System.Windows.Forms assembly from the list.

But is it *okay* to do this? Is it *okay* to reference WindowsForms from a Class Library?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  Very hard to see why this spooks you.  It cannot possibly be a problem because whatever project uses your class also needs to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.  Without it, the compiler will complain because it has no idea what a PictureBox class might be.

Comment: Thank you @UlugbekUmirov and HansPassant.

Comment: This answer will be more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509951/use-windows-forms-in-a-net-core-class-library-net-core-control-library

Comment: This answer will be more useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509951/use-windows-forms-in-a-net-core-class-library-net-core-control-library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is totally okay to do this.

`System.Windows.Forms` is just an assembly like any others. There is no special treatment to the project file, as with for example Office add-ins.

You can safely add this assembly to your project file.

Comment: Oh, you can close if you like. I thought I had already accepted the answer.

Comment: Just FYI, @spike.y; Closing is not for questions that are solved. Questions here aren't so much "support requests" as part of a searchable repository of information that could be helpful to people in the future. Further answers are always welcome, in fact, in case someone has an alternate solution that could apply. That may not help *you*, but it could help a future reader.