# Use Windows Forms in a .Net Core Class Library - .NET Core Control Library

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I am trying to create a .net core 3 class library that references the .net core 3 version of winform (so this assembly can itself be referenced by a .net core 3 WinForm assembly).

A new .net core WinForm project references Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms, however I can't find any nuget package with that name.

What do I need to do to reference the .net core 3 winform?

Comment: Is "net core 3 winform" a thing? Are you trying to *migrate* old winforms application into .net core?

Comment: [It looks](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) very beta to me, Google say release is September 2019. Without form designer.. kek.

Comment: I am trying to write from scratch (not migrating) a WinForm helper assembly to be shared between .net core 3 WinForm applications. There is a UI to create a .net core 3 WinForm application. I just can't find a way to create a .net core 3 class assembly referencing WinForm.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **Update:** In later versions of VS 2019 (I tried Version 16.8.2) there is a project template for *Windows Forms Control Library* for .NET Core.

Currently [Windows Forms .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) is in Preview mode and I don't know any official Nuget package or Project template for Windows Forms Control Library in .NET Core in VS 2019 16.2.2.

But to create a **Windows Forms Control Library**, you can use the following instructions:

1. Add a new project of type *Class Library (.NET Core)*
2. After project created, right click on project file and choose *Edit Project File*
3. Change the project SDK to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`
4. Specify windows forms as UI technology by adding `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`.

Now the project file should be like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now you can add Windows forms elements like `Form` or `UserControl` to this project and build the project without any problem.

Comment: If for some reason you are looking for dlls, you can find them in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\3.0.0-preview6-27626-01\ref\netcoreapp3.0` (depending to installed version of the framework).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the "System.Windows.Forms" namespace isn't made available in that project.

Comment: I've already tried it with the mentioned version of Visual Studio and everything worked properly. Just try adding a `UserControl` or a `Form` and build it after adding.

Comment: Double checked everything with the mentioned version of VS and it works properly.

Comment: So just for the avoidance of doubt, I don't believe I can use .Net core 3 on the regular version of Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio 16.3.0 Preview 2.0, and .Net Core 3.0.100 preview 8 (both the latest versions). What I tried is changing the sdk of the project and reloading it, I haven't tried referencing the assemblies from the folder manually. Adding a UserControl or Form to the class libary project doesn't seem to do anything or add any reference. Perhaps the Preview 8 is broken, but it is surprising it would be that broken a few weeks away from general release.

Comment: I'm using `3.0.100-preview6-011644`  and `VS 2019 16.2.2`. I didn't add any reference, the path to dlls is just for your information.

Comment: Ok so I got it to work, so apparently it also requires to add in the csproj file, inside PropertyGroup, "<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>". Might be worth editing your response if anyone else runs in the same problem.

Comment: @Charles The reason which I didn't mention that was because it should work even without that (in fact was working well for me.) Anyway, I added it.

Comment: Hello Reza, great answer and it's working for netcoreapp3.0. I had the feeling i had to close visual studio once before it started working. Do you know a way to also have it work for .netstandard2.0 and .netstandard2.1. I haven't been able to do that yet.

Comment: @JRB Did you ever figure out how to do this with Standard 2.1?

Comment: I haven't tried that with netstandard. If I tried, I'll let you know.

Comment: @Pushkin, compiling the class library with netstandard 2.0 and 2.1 is not the hard problem, but in my solutions, where I have WCF and EF Core projects in these  solutions I was not able to let all the projects work together using netstandard 2.0 and 2.1 class libraries, so I gave up on that. I had some success however with class libraries compiled in netcoreapp3.1.

Comment: @JRB Thanks for the update. That does appear to be the right thing to do to get winforms to work; class assembly for core not standard

Answer (score 9):

I had a core 3.1 web app referring to a Framework 4.5.2 project that had dependencies on System.Windows.Forms. The fix for me was to add the below line to web app csproj file:

**FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms"**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: this worked for my situation, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The currently accepted answer appears to be somewhat outdated. The recent syntax requires the target to be specified in the TargetFramework tag, not in the Sdk tag:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

More info here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Answer (score 3):

In alternative you can add a new project of Windows Form Type and than set the output type to Libray.

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, with net5 I needed the following in my project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```